# Rewrite rule in wordpress for wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm running wordpress in my local with "ben.scbw.zec.dev" vhost.

I have created page template to display particular event detail.

http://ben.scbw.zec.dev/event-view?view_event=14

I can access page with above url "event-view" is slug on page and page id = 439 .

Now, I desire to access it with below url.

http://ben.scbw.zec.dev/event-view/this-is-test-event/14/

"this-is-test-event" its fro titel of event any text , i have manage to create URl.

Below is code from my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Above is Standard wordpress crated code and i have added following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^event-view/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ ./index.php?page_id=439&titel=$1&view_event=$2 [L]
```

here 439 is in page id for "even-view" as i mentioned.

But, I'm not able to access page with "http://ben.scbw.zec.dev/event-view/this-is-test-event/14/" url. it shows me 404 not found error.
I have been trying this for 4-5 day but not able to find solution.

I'm really very Thank full if anyone can help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, wordpress uses internal RewriteRules to map an url.
So you don't have to add an additional RewriteRule-tag to your htaccess.
You have to register your query parameter and add rewrite rules to the internal wordpress rewrite engine.

@see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/add_query_var/
@see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/